# save the changes in notepad

Tags: c#, notepad

i am making a notepad in c#. this is the save part of the file. but the problem is that if i modify the text and save again, it asks to save a new file instead of saving in original file.

```
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save file";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text;
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "TEXT|*.txt|DOC|*.doc|DOCX|*.docx|RICH TEXT FILE|*.rtf|ALL FILES|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's because you're prompting the user with a save file dialog.

Comment: Why not use directly `tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text` in the `SaveFile` call?

Answer (score 3):

Use a private field in your class that has the value of the last saved file

```
var currentFileName = "";

    .....

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save file";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text;
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "TEXT|*.txt|DOC|*.doc|DOCX|*.docx|RICH TEXT FILE|*.rtf|ALL FILES|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        bool save = true;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentFileName))
        {
            var result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
            {
                currentFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            else
            {
                save = false;
            }
        }

        if (save)
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(currentFileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep showing the save file dialog then this is what you get. `(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog())`

Best would be:

- Create internal string variable containing the path. (default is "") (or use `tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text`)
- If path is not set, show file dialog, save result in path
- If path is set, save file

Answer (score 0):

set .OverWritePrompt to false for your SaveFileDialog

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.overwriteprompt.aspx

Comment: Not the issue. (Atleast judging from the OP)

Comment: -1 As a PC user, I think this is the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: I'm just answering his question about how to avoid the prompt.  The bool is there for a reason, if he wants to use it that's his call.

Comment: The prompt is caused by repeat calling 'saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()'. Your answer is about overwriting the same file, which is something different.